# A list in which sum of every item individually equals to 10 for example [ [1,3,3,2,1] , [4,2,2,1,1], ......]. But it doesn't work properly

Tags: python, list, if-statement, types, while-loop

Im trying to find a list `front_design_array` in which sum of every element equals to 10. Starting with `array` and `f_ext_ele_groups`. In each iteration, the elements in `array` is appended in `f_ext_ele_groups`. For exapmle, after first iteration, `f_ext_ele_groups` would turn into

```
[[1,1], [1,2],[1,3]...[1,9], [2,1], [2,2]......[2,8]......[3,1], [3,2]......[3,7]...............[9,1]]
```

At the end, `front_design_array` should contain, for example, `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` (its sum is 10) and `[3,3,3,1]`. After very iteration, the elements of `f_ext_ele_groups` is controlled for any elements whether equals to 10. If true, it is appended to `front_design_array`.

But `front_design_array` eventually just contained

```
[[10], [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2, 3], [6, 1, 2, 1], [7, 1, 2], [7, 1, 2], [9, 1], [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2, 3, 1], [5, 1, 2, 1, 1], [5, 1, 2, 1, 1], [6, 1, 2, 1], [8, 1, 1]]
```

and doesnt contain for example `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` (its sum is 10) and `[3,3,3,1]` (its sum is 10).

Where is my fault?

Here is my code:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
f_ext_ele_groups= [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
                              
front_design_array=[]          
length=len(f_ext_ele_groups)

while length > 0:               

    draft= []
    
    for x in f_ext_ele_groups:  
                                
        sumation= sum(x)
        
        if sumation ==10:
            front_design_array.append(x)
    
        elif sumation < 10:
            
            for ele in array:
                var=x  
                sum_t=int(sumation+ ele)
  
                if sum_t <= 10:
                    var=x  
                    var.append(ele)
                    draft.append(var)
                    var=[]
                
                elif sum_t > 10:
                    continue
        
    f_ext_ele_groups=draft    
    length=len(draft)
```

Comment: Likely [python - List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent) .

Comment: NOW IT WORKS !!

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY SOLVED. For use an element from a list in iteration, .copy() should be used ! I forgot it for `var=x` if you look carefully. It should be `var=x.copy()`.